# Tailwindcss not rebuilding output.css when using --watch

Tags: tailwind-css, hot-reload

I created a new project using tailwindcss but it doesnt rebuild the css output when call npm run dev (wish include --watch for hotreload)

I have created other simpliest proyect. A single html and its css following the also simple tailwind steps from its site with no luck.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/output.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="font-bold text-5xl text-red-400">Test</h1>
        <p class="italic p-5 bg-red-400">Non in deserunt fugiat commodo deserunt qui esse labore         tempor excepteur dolor. </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/*.{html,js}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

package.json

```
{
      "name": "testtailwind",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
       }
    }
```

File structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfiW.png)

For making the output reflect the changes I have to stop (ctrl + c) and run npm run dev again.
Please help, thanks